# Expression in SSRS for Hiding columns

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have developed SSRS Report. I am calling this report from C# code and passing filter parameters from there.I have to show the columns depending on one of the filer values received from code.Hence I am using below expression.

=IIF(Instr(JOIN(Parameters!Metrics.value,","),"5")>0,False,True)

But this is causing problem because report renders all values for Metrics 5,15,25,.... etc.Please suggest me solution so that it will take only that specific value.I tried using InstrRev as well but no luck.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you only expecting 1 value or many values for the filter?

If 1, then you can set the Filter Parameters!Metrics.Value = 5 or '5'

If many, set the Filter Parameters!Metrics.Value IN then put your join(parameters...  in the expression.

This will set the filter to only show those rows in the dataset...

That is for FILTERS... if you mean you are trying to put this in the Visibility property, then I think it would be better to make a nested IIF or a Switch statement - then it will check 1:1..

```
ex. IIF([field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value," ").GetValue(0)
     OR [field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value," ").GetValue(1), False, True)

or Switch( [field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value," ").GetValue(0), False
           [field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value," ").GetValue(0), False, True)
```

I am assuming the field value is being compared against the Parameter value... or some comparison.. Make sure to Split on however you are sending it in...

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But I think we have to write separate function to get whole string in Array and then to do comparison.I tried this IIF([field value] =Split(ParametersMetrics.Value," ").GetValue(0)
     OR [field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value," ").GetValue(1), False, True) , but it is throwing error. Alternatively I have thought of writing saparate function that accepts whole filter value in strig format as one parameter and string to search as second parameter and then to perform exact comparison there and return result at expression.Please suggest.

Comment: @Mandar what error are you getting?  in the code you put in your comment, I notice that you don't have the ! after Parameters in the first split- not sure if that was just you typing... Also, if your string is comma delimited, you need to put the comma in the Split statement '[field value] =Split(Parameters!Metrics.Value,",").GetValue(1)'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=IIF(Instr("," & JOIN(Parameters!Metrics.value,",") & ",",",5,")>0,False,True)